# C++ - Include file from NuGet package overrides local include file: How change include path?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, nuget-package

A C++ NuGet package, which my C++ project needs, contains a header file `header.hpp`.

My local project also contains a header file `header.hpp` but with different content.

During compilation the NuGet header is included instead of my local header, obviously resulting in compiler errors. How can I change that include path order?

<sub>Renaming either file is not an option.</sub>

<sub>Neither is adding the local header to "Forced Include Files" even though that makes the project compile.</sub>

Comment: Two options (1) experimentation with include path order or (2) rename your header file.  I would do (2) unless I had time and thought the experimentation worth it.

Comment: HOW do I change the include path order? NuGet packages seem to magically take precedence.

Comment: You'd have to manually edit the vcxproj file, or else create a NuGet package that does nothing except modify the search path and make sure it comes after the other one in the project includes.

Comment: The vcxproj file (tag: AdditionalIncludeDirectories) does not contain the NuGet package path. Only an ImportGroup/Import tag refers to the NuGet package. What to edit?

Comment: @AHalvar Did you find the answer for this mate?

Comment: @ZoomIn, seven years later I am doing C++ and Python and have forgotten all about NuGet quirks and the project that triggered this question :)

Comment: @AHalvar That's alright mate, I found a temporary workaround.